# Execute JMeterPluginsCMD.sh from JMeter sampler or preprocessor

Tags: jmeter

I'm using below command in a Linux machine to generate csv file from jtl file.

```
JMeterPluginsCMD.sh --generate-csv AggregateReport.csv --input-jtl testresults.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

Is it possible to execute this command from JMeter using any sampler/pre-processor ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler)

> OS Process Sampler is a sampler that can be used to execute commands on the local machine.
> It should allow execution of any command that can be run from the command line.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. It might be a good idea to add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true
   ```

   otherwise you may have incomplete test data
2. In order to be able to execute external 3rd-party programs from JMeter you can use [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) configured like:

   [image]
3. It's also a good idea to put this OS Process Sampler under the [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group)

More information:

- [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)
- [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)